# HAProxy SSL with new GoDaddy certs

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy

I renewed my certificate from GoDaddy and I got back two files:

`gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`
`27ec89cfaa7c28.crt`

I have the `private.key`.

However I totally forgot how to use, or produce, a valid `.pem` file to use with HAProxy, my current configuration line reads:

`bind :443 ssl crt /home/ubuntu/ssl/site.pem ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!AESGCM`

I guess it must be password-less. Tried to look up info about this but I got nowhere.

Any kind soul that can tell me how should I concatenate those files in order for HAProxy to work?

Comment: I would assume it works like for `stunnel` - make sure the server certificate is first in the `.pem` file, with the certificate chain below them.

Comment: should I concat `27ec..` > `gd_bundle` > `private key` in that order?

Comment: I like to have the private key on top, but yes, that would likely work. I don't really know the contents of those files, so this is me guessing. You can check with `openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer -in 27ec89cfaa7c28.crt` and the same command upon the bundle. The subject of the server cert should be your domain, and the issuer should be identical to the subject of the first certificate in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced problem with pem files previous. It appears to matter what order the key and crt files are listed in the pem file. Use cat example.com.crt example.com.key > example.com.pem to create a new pem file rather than using the supplied one.